# Integer root of a quadratic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

Determine the sum of all (distinct) positive integers $ n$ , such that for some integer $a$,

$$ n^2 -an + 6a = 0. $$

Comment: where did you find this problem? have you tried anything?

Comment: I saw it on net

Comment: Do you mean over all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ or just some specific $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $n^2-an+6a=0$ has integer solution(s) $n$ ? If it's a specific $a$ then don't you just need to use the quadratic formula, assuming your integer $a$ gives integer solutions for $n$?

Answer (score 7):

Solve for $a$: $a=\frac{n^2}{n-6}=n+\frac{36}{n-6}+6$ which is an integer when $n-6$ divides $36$, i.e. $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 24, 42\}$, whose sum is 159.

Comment: nice work. i didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to
$$
a(n-6) = n^2.
$$
So we are looking for all $n$ such that $n-6$ divides $n^2$.
Polynomial long division of $n^2$ by $n-6$ gives $n^2 = (n-6)(n+6) + 36$, so equivalently, $n-6$ divides $36$.

Enumeration of the divisors of $36$ yields
$$
n-6\in\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 9,\pm 12,\pm 18,\pm 36\}.
$$
Since $n$ is required to be positive, the answer is
$$
n\in\{2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,12,15,18,24,42\}.
$$